# Fatal Error no se encuentra la clase conexión en la linea 33

Tags: php, mysql, conexión

Buen dia, tengo este error busque en varios foros y en las preguntas similares pero no tengo una solución clara  pego el código de, intente usar spl_autoload_register() en la función myautoload, pero me muestra los errores de que las constantes SISTEMA y DS no están definidas y de igual forma con ese cambio sigue sin encontrar la clase Conexión

```
    <?php
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    | Carga automática Clases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    */
    function myautoload($NombreClase) {
       if (file_exists(SISTEMA.'clase' . DS . strtolower($NombreClase) . '.clase.php')) {
          require_once(SISTEMA.'clase' . DS . strtolower($NombreClase) . '.clase.php');
    
     }
    }

   //Instanciar Clases
   $db              = new Conexion();   --> line 33
   $usuario     = new Usuario();
   $enlace          = new Enlace();
   $sistema     = new Sistema();
   $Vendedor        = new Vendedor();
   $notificacion    = new Notificacion();
   $EstadoCuenta    = new EstadoCuenta();
   $ProductosClase  = new Productos();
   $CajaDeVenta = new Venta();

   // Ejecutar Algunas Clases
   $sistema->ReportarError();
   ?>
```

y el constructor es el siguiente que esta en otro archivo

and the constructor is the following one that is in another file
<?php

```
    class Conexion {

    private $mysqli;

    function __construct() {
    }

    public function Conectar(){

    $this->mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DB, PORT);
    // Soporte para caracteres especiales en la base de datoss
    $this->mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
        die("Error al conectar con la base de datos (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ") " .    mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    // Devolver recurso de conexión
    return $this->mysqli;
   }

    public function SQL($sqlconsulta){
       return $this->Conectar()->query($sqlconsulta);
    }
   }
```

al realizar el llamado es donde muestra el error
when making the call is where it shows the error

Comment: Dices que te da error porque las constantes no están definidas... pero es que no están definidas. Si no registras el autoloader, debes incluir las clases manualmente con include('ruta/nombre_archivo.php');

Comment: Cuando usas mecanismos de "autocarga" debe existir un archivo en el que se indican las rutas sobre las que va a operar el "autoloader" ¿lo creaste? Si es así, ¿está en el, la ruta al directorio que contiene tus archivos de código para esas clases? Si no has hecho eso usa include() o include_once() como te sugiere @Benito-B

Comment: tengo definidas  las variables                                               

//Archivos Estaticos del Proyecto
define('ESTATICO',URLBASE.'estatico/');
// Directorio Root del Proyecto
define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
// Directorio del Sistema del Proyecto
define('SISTEMA', __ROOT__.DS.'sistema'.DS);
// Directorio de las Clases del Proyecto
define('CLASE', SISTEMA.DS.'clase'.DS);
// Directorio de los modulos del Proyecto
define('MODULO', SISTEMA.'modulo'.DS.'');

Comment: Lee [spl_autoload_register](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.spl-autoload-register.php)

Comment: Va a parecer tonta la pregunta ¿esas constantes están disponibles? al momento de ejecutar tu autoload, ¿apuntan a dónde supones? has un var_dump y verificas.

Comment: Muestra el código donde incluyes el archivo en el cual defines las constantes.

Comment: revise modifique el código pero me sigue mostrando el error de no reconocer la ubicación de la clase conexión

Comment: Para usar las constantes debes incluir el archivo donde las defines. ¿Lo estás haciendo? ¿Dónde lo haces?

Comment: lo tengo en otra pagina que la llamo por medio de un require_once

Comment: Dices que lo llamas mediante require_once pero en el primer archivo que pusiste no se ve el require_once en ningún lado, con lo cual en ese archivo no están definidas las constantes. Debes incluir el archivo donde están definidas antes de poder usarlas en el autoloader.